# Is there any to fix or restore data from a Fusion Drive, when it kernel panic loops but drives are ok? Even crashes with cloned drives

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, kernel-panic

iMac 2013 27" 1Tb HD & 128Gb SSD Fusion Drive
Error message is:

panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800ec1d80d): "CoreStorage: load_lfs_from_seg: ran out of free segments\n"@/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/d7e177bcf5/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreStorage/CoreStorage-554.140.2/core/lfs.cpp:3218

It will reboot and loop the iMac on startup **and** any other mac that the two drives are plugged into and give the same kernel panic.

One of the drives on it's own is ok (but not mounted)but as soon as you plug in the other it panics.

Tested both drives individually with Disk Util, Disk Warrior, Drive Genius Surface Test; both ok.

Even the cloned drive versions will do the same. So must be related to the CoreStorage system?

Would like to know what this means: "CoreStorage: load_lfs_from_seg: ran out of free segments"

Thanks

Dave

Comment: "One of the drives on its own is ok" - which one? The HDD can work fine on its own if you need to be able to boot or access data. The SSD is really just acting as a cache & is not critical to the operation. If you can mount it, I'd recommend copying off or cloning to an SSD & life will be sweet ;) Those old hybrid iMacs were terribly slow. An SSD would put a real spring in its step. Fusion hybrids were a stop-gap for when SSDs were too expensive, they've had their day.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Either one. The problem is that it crashes any machine when you plug both drives into it, even cloned versions. Can;t read the data on the HD on it's own. Something to do with the 128Gb SSD fusion drive version being different. The iMac is going for SSD upgrade yes. Dave

Comment: hmmm… if it can't read the HD, then I'm not sure what to suggest, other than the usual suite of repair apps.